# Does the usage of named cells in VBA code slow down the macro?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, named-ranges

> Does the usage of named cells in VBA code slow down the macro?

I assume that if you use one or two named cells/ranges in your VBA code it does not affect its execution time a lot. However, I am curious about whether the excessive usage of named cells/ranges will slow down the macro.

Comment: The answer is: It depends on what you are doing.  You'll need to test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Impact of Named Ranges on SpreadSheet:

I found the following information.

```
Named Ranges:
1. allows users to save time
2. enhances automated data analysis
But:
3. increases the size of files and significantly 
   slows down basic Excel functionality.
```

Refer: https://medium.com/@rzacharia/excel-named-ranges-the-good-and-the-really-ugly-894e04fb16e5

> Impact of Named Ranges on VBA Execution:

It depends on how you are using it. 
For example, if you have created large number of named ranges and you are calling those in loop then it will slow down the performance. Because every time excel will need to resolve the name.

And if you are using Range("A1:A30") instead of Named Range then Excel don't need perform any extra operation as compared to Named Range.

To test this I created one Named Range (A1:A30) and called it in loop with different count and this is what I found (Time mentioned is in seconds).

```
NamedRange  Range   Loop Count
1.64         1.57   100000
3.3          3.17   200000
8.38         7.9    500000
```

Conclusion:

```
1. If you are using Named Range with limited number and not using in loop with larger count then it may not create any issue.
2. It may slow down the performance 
   2.1 if you are using Named Range in loop with large count.
   2.2 if you are using large number of Named Ranges.
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I already came across this article. However, it only deals with named ranges/cells in the context of excel spreadsheets and how the spreadsheet itself slows down in. It says nothing about the execution time of VBA macros.

Comment: Any idea about "large number of named range ?" , if we have 20 or 30, this means we have a lot for named range ? and it will be slower or you are talking about hundreds and thousands ?